# (Joomla) Can I eliminate a slideshow in a homepage only for the mobile version of a website?

Tags: mobile, joomla, content-management-system, gallery

I'm creating the mobile version of a website. I'm using Joomla 2.5 and the template I used is Gantry (http://www.gantry-framework.org/).
This template support the mobile version and it make avaible a set of setting in the backend of Joomla.

Now, I can't remove the slideshow in the homepage ONLY for mobile version because it's too expensive.
Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up Chrome Dev Tools, Firebug, or any other tool that allows you to inspect the website. Inspect the Slideshow area to get the main element ID or class, then open the following file:

```
root/libraries/gantry/css/grid-responsive.css
```

On line 173, you will see the following code, which defines a mobile device screen size.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
```

Inside that, add the following code:

```
.wk-gallery-showcase { display: none; }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The web site is www.ilmondoinmoto.com

Comment: @user2131170 - I have updated my anser with the exact code you have to add.

Comment: I try to insert the code in grid-responsive.css but didn't work. So I found in the same folder another css called "iphone-gantry.css" and I put in the line you tell me and it works, but only for iPhone. How can I solve for the other devices?

Comment: ahh, I wasn't aware they has a specific iPhone css file. I am now pretty sure that the file I provided you with and iPhone.css are the 2 mains CSS files that controll the responsive layout for ALL devices ;)

Comment: [iphone-gantry.css](http://pastebin.com/Cz6fe5dX) This is the css I tell you. Could you take a look?

Comment: ok, in which case add `.wk-gallery-showcase { display: none; }` anywhere in that file

Comment: I do, but it's work only for iPhone. The slideshow is still visible on Android device. I'm getting crazy! :)

Comment: did you add it to both CSS files?

Comment: Ok, it's working!Now I have to test tablets and a Windows Phone. Thanks a lot for your helps!